# Can someone explain the regular expression part of String#replaceAll(..) method?

Tags: java, regex, string

```
//Its a question on replacement of duplicate characters

public class RemoveDuplicateChars {

    static String testcase1 = "DPMD Jayawardene";

    public static void main(String args[]){
        RemoveDuplicateChars testInstance= new RemoveDuplicateChars();
        String result = testInstance.remove(testcase1);
        System.out.println(result);

    }
    //write your code here
    public String remove(String str){
        return str.replaceAll("(.)(?=.*\\1)", "");//how this replacement working
    }       
}
```

Comment: Use [this](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl)

Answer (score 2):

As you can see from the name of the class - it removes characters that repeat in a string.

Breakdown:
`(.)` - stands for any character, the brackets are used for grouping, so we'll be able to reference it later on using `\1`

`(?=)` - lookahead

`(?=.*\\1)` - we're looking forward 
`.*` consuming any number of characters and looking for our first character`\1`

If the regex is truthy, the referenced character will be replaced with the empty string.

See ***[Fiddle](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl?regex=%28.%29%28?=.%2a%5C1%29)***

Comment: Does the `(` in front of `?=` start its own capture group?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis yes it does, but in this case it would be same as `(.)`

Comment: Nope. `(?=XXX)` will look forward for "XXX". The opening and closing brackets her are used as opening and closing tokens for the "look ahead"

Comment: @alfasin if you redo w/ Pattern and Matcher you would end up with two groups; group(0) that corresponds to `(.)` and group(1) that correspond to positive look ahead

Comment: @user1631616 are you sure it works with all flavors (that support lookahead) ?

Comment: @alfasin positive/negative look ahead/behind def works with `Pattern/Matcher` as i used it for one of my projects. If you rewrite what OP has w/ Pattern/Matcher - you can see that whenever it matches there are 2 grps hence `Does the ( in front of ?= start its own capture group?` the answer is yes :)

Comment: @user1631616 you ignored my question. I understand that it works in Java, but I doubt it'll work with other flavor of regex. That said, I'll definitely try it sometime soon with Python, Ruby, and JS - thanks!

Comment: @alfasin i guess i miss understood your question (my bad)

Answer (score 2):

From [java.util.Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html):

- `(.)` : Match any character in a capture group (basically a variable named `\1`)
- `(?=` : Zero-width positive lookahead (make sure the rest of the string matches)

  - `.*` any number of characters followed by
  - `\\1` the captured group

In other words, it matches any character that also appears later in the string (i.e. is a duplicate). In Java, this would be:

```
for(int i=0; i<str.length(); i++) { 
  char captured = str.charAt(i); // (.)
  if (str.substring(i+1).matches(".*" + captured))  { // (?=.*\1)
    // the char is a duplicate, replace it with "" 
  }
}
```